# don't load web site's image

Tags: google-chrome, images, blocking, google-chrome-extensions, adblock

There is a web site with an annoying image which I just don't want to see and which I don't want my colleagues to see. Is there a way to not load it? Maybe have an application to block it from incoming traffic? Or maybe there is a chrome plugin for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Adblock](http://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom) (initially for Firefox, but there's also a Chrome plugin).

Comment: Awesome!!! That's just what I needed! Thanks!